# Library that supports XPath 2.0 in Python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, libxml2, xpath-2.0

Is it possible to use XPath 2.0 functions like `starts-with()`, `ends-with()` and `contains()` in Python? I was trying to use `lxml` and `defusedxml`, but unfortunately they do not support any of these functions.

I know I can use `substring()` or `matches()` for workaround, but I have really complicated case, so it would be nicer to deal with more readable functions.

Any lib that supports XPath 2.0 spec?

Comment: I can [highly recommend elementpath](https://github.com/sissaschool/elementpath).

Comment: Check out [SaxonC](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation11/index.html)

Comment: Also if you’re just needing to use regex in xpath, lxml supports exslt. [See here.](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath)

Comment: Not sure what defusedxml is, but starts-with and contains are 1.0 functions so plain lxml should handle them fine (using .xpath() method). (matches is 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[saxonpy](https://pypi.org/project/saxonpy/) is based on Saxon He and supports Xpath 2.0.
You can check the github repo for some examples to get you started:

https://github.com/tennom/saxonpy

Answer (score 0):

The python wheels for SaxonC 12.X is the official release, which you can find here: https://pypi.org/user/saxonica/

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to use [elementpath](https://elementpath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this, which supports the built-in xml.etree module and lxml.

```py
>>> import elementpath
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> root = ElementTree.XML('<A><B1/><B2><C1/><C2/><C3/></B2></A>')
>>> elementpath.select(root, '/A/B2/*')
[<Element 'C1' at ...>, <Element 'C2' at ...>, <Element 'C3' at ...>]
```